# Loading line and multipolygons into QGIS on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Tags: qgis-2, raspberry-pi

I try to load line and multipolygon shapefile layer to QGIS in Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) and it appear like this:

[image]

Although I use the same shapefile layer in Windows 10 and it load without any problem and it appear like this:

[image]

I'm using QGIS 2.18. Can anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: are you sure those are the same file? they seem to have different names and extents (the Pi one is certainly not in EPSG:4326)

Comment: I only changed the name ,and now check the properties and I found it in EPSG:4326,WGS 84, another thing the layer in the beginning does not show anything, it appear like this when I zoom out